# Show minus Laplacian operator is densely defined on $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> 1. Let $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a bounded and smooth domain, and $L$ be the minus Lapacian operator with zero boundary condition. Prove that 
>      $$L : L^2(U) \rightarrow L^2(U)$$
>      is a densely defined, unbounded linear operator with domain $D(L) = H^2(U) \cap H^1_0(U)$.
> 2. Give an example showing that the difference between $H^2_0(U)$ and $H^2(U)\cap H^1_0(U)$.

Here $H^2(U)$ is the Sobolev space $W^{2,2}(U)$ and $H^1_0(U)$ denotes the closure of $C^{\infty}(U)$ in $H^1(U)$.

---

I really have no clue. Should we use Green formula to define how does the minus Laplacian operator apply to a function from the above Sobolev space?

Any hints or answers are welcomed!

Comment: You should check the well-definedness of the operator as well as that the domain $D(L)$ is indeed dense in the Hilbert space.

Comment: @Luke thanks for your comments. Could you tell me how does we define Laplace operator on the sobolev space. I thought it can only be defined on $C^2$.

Comment: For "densely defined", you were told what the domain was, namely $D(L) = H^2(U) \cap H^1_0(U)$, and so you have to show this space is dense in $L^2(U)$.  Well, $D(L)$ contains the compactly supported smooth functions $C_c^\infty(U)$, and hopefully you know that $C_c^\infty(U)$ is dense in $L^2(U)$.  This part of the question has nothing to do with what the operator $L$ actually does.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes I think this part is clear to me. Could you explain the other part or some reference?